# Can't push to github from Android Studio all of a sudden

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I wasn't having any problems pushing to my remote repository, but I'm now getting the following error:

```
8:48:11 PM EmptyThrowable: Repository not found for root C:\*\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi
```

I checked my remote repository and it looks like the `drawable-mdpi` folder is not there. I'm not sure why, but shouldn't git just resolve this since I've added and committed all files to the local repository?

Comment: Is your drawable-mdpi folder is in local system ?

Comment: Yes, I can see and interact with it on my machine